# Is there a solution to use seaborn with streamlit if my app is blanck using seaborn?

Tags: seaborn, streamlit

MacOS + streamlit + Python 3.9.

I have an issue using seaborn.

```py
import seaborn as sns

nb_currentprovider = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.countplot(x="current_provider",data=df_ventes)

plt.title("Répartition des ventes selon l'opérateur actuel du client", fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel("Volume de ventes", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("Opérateur actuel", fontsize=12);
st.pyplot(nb_currentprovider)
```

My app is blank, I had the same problem with matplotlib but now it is working with:

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import RendererAgg
_lock = RendererAgg.lock
```

Does a similar solution exist for seaborn?

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: @ferdy import seaborn as sns (only that) is blocking streamlit (app blank)

Comment: Since seaborn is basically just a wrapper and produces Matplotlib figures, you can show them as regular Matplotlib figures with streamlit. However I would recommend you to look into plotly or altair as they give you interactive plots.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example on windows 10 using seaborn.

###### Code

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import streamlit as st 


titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
sns.countplot(x="class", data=titanic)

st.pyplot(fig)
```

##### Output

[image]